# MySQL select into outfile "file already exists" and "file does not exist" duality (?) case

Tags: mysql, csv, centos, mariadb, systemd

I ran this command successfully on my CentOS machine's MariaDB:

```
MariaDB> select * from foobar into outfile '/tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv'
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';

Query OK, 900 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

### Cat is alive? No.

You'd expect to find '/tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv'. Me too. I `ls` it:

```
# ls /tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv

ls: cannot access /tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv: No such file or directory
```

### Cat is dead? No.

What? So I went back to the MariaDB command line client and run the same SQL again:

```
MariaDB> select * from foobar into outfile '/tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv'
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';

ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '/tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv' already exists
```

### Cat is alive exclusively for MariaDB? No.

I thought maybe the MariaDB is accessing another file system? So I tried this:

```
MariaDB> \! ls /tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv;

ls: cannot access /tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv: No such file or directory
```

So, no.

Any idea what happened? How do I get the file '/tmp/schrodinger_cat.csv'?

Comment: `sudo ls /tmp/*.csv`?

Comment: Nah. I tried `ls` with root account too. Not a permission issue. The output file is simply not there.

Comment: Is MariaDB on a different server? Have you ensured that you're accessing /tmp on that box?

Comment: Nope. Same server.

Comment: Humor me and do `sudo ls -la /tmp/*.csv`. Perhaps it's hidden?

Comment: `ls: cannot access /tmp/*.csv: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it is exclusive for MariaDB.

```
# ls /tmp/systemd-private-*-mariadb.service-*/tmp

/tmp/systemd-private-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-mariadb.service-xxx/tmp:
schrodinger_cat.csv
```

The reason is that the CentOS systemd service file set `PrivateTmp` to `true`:

```
[Unit]
Description=MariaDB database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=mysql
Group=mysql

ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n
# Note: we set --basedir to prevent probes that might trigger SELinux alarms,
# per bug #547485
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=300

# Place temp files in a secure directory, not /tmp
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You may find more information from [this RedHat blog post](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1976243). If `PrivateTmp=true` the process will have a, well, private `/tmp` folder.

Turn out the cat is alive and well in a private castle :-)

Comment: And when they say "private", they mean private!  Unless you are the mysqld user, you simply cannot get to the generated file.  I had to set PrivateTmp=false and then run my job as root so I can kill the darned cat, er, file.

Comment: Another reason for me to hate MariaDB. Sadly, I'm on Ubuntu so I'm unsure where they put the file. Where did you find the systemd service file?